# RewriteRule in same .htaccess on two different files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I want to make a rewrite rule that will work on two different files which are contained in the same folder.

```
localhost/nameOfUser will be applied to index.php
localhost/nameOfUser?score=12 or localhost/nameOfUser/12 will be applied to post.php
```

I've managed to make the first one work with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(css|fonts)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(php|avatars)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(user|post)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?user=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

if I add

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ post.php?user=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

The second starts to work, but the first one doesn't.

Is it even possible to make rewrite for two different files in the same .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

Give the following rules a try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(css|fonts|php|avatars|user|post)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?user=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ post.php?user=$1&score=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

However, if you want `nameOfUser?score=12` to work, you'll need to modify them to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(css|fonts|php|avatars|user|post)($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?user=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^score=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) /post.php?user=$1&score=%1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: On localhost/user/score doesn't show css. Just plain text.

Comment: @Mirakurun Update your HTML to include the `<base href="/">` tag. It should appear at the beginning of your `<head>` tag.